# Target Android/iOS in vNext class library

Tags: c#, android, ios, mono, asp.net-core

Is it possible at this time (ASP.NET 5.0 beta 7) to target mono, Android, iOS or a portable class library? If yes, how?

When adding the "MonoAndroid10" target in project.json, I cannot use any of the NuGet packages from packages like "dotnet", as they all have folders that disable support for them.

However, no runtime or framework packages will actually work. Immediately as I build, it starts complaining that no type is actually registered (System.Object, System.String, etc.), and the build fails.

This also holds true for portable class libraries, targeting Windows Phone or Silverlight directly.

Does anyone have any clue as how to achieve such portability?

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps could try using a `.nuspec` file to describe your package and specify `MonoAndroid10` as new target:

`[YourPackakageSpecificationFile].nuspec`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package [...]
   <files> [...]
       <file src="bin/Release/[YourDll].dll" target="lib/MonoAndroid10" />
   </files>
</package>
```

And finally, build the package by invoking the NuGet command (`nuget pack [YourPackakageSpecificationFile].nuspec`)

The `nuget spec` call can help you generate such a file.

You'll next have to (or not) get your dependencies statified against the given framwork ...

Comment: This question is hopelessly outdated, as the .NET guys have since properly updated their documentation, but, just to clarify, this answer misses the point completely and entirely. The fact that I define a nuspec target will not help in any way the fact that the libraries that I have to depend depend upon do not actually have any support for MonoAndroid10.